# conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1 android when i run the app

Tags: android

Hi iam trying to run my app but it will not executed it will display error like "conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1 android" please help me how can i get back from this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had also this error, it is related to adding same jar files twice in build path. Please check your build path in project properties. You may find same library linked twice from two different locations.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that libraries that you included in your app can be executed in Android?

Comment: yes  pulata.sridhar@gmail.com